# how to check which button is clicked in action script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making game in action script i want that when user selest any region etc then the value of that region must be selected i have 7  regions. how to identify which is the clicked button or selected region

Comment: Do you have any code currently?  If so please post it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question not very clear, but you can add a mouse listener to check if a button is clicked. You can use `event.target` to detect which button you actually clicked on.

```
this.mcButton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleButtonClick);
this.mcButton2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleButtonClick);
this.mcButton3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleButtonClick);

function handleButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var button:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
    trace('I am clicked: ' + button);
}
```

Comment: You need to give all buttons an instance name. Click on a button, Go to the property inspector, fill the name. Do the exact thing for the other buttons. To enter the code, open the actions window, shortcut = F9. Hope that helps. I would suggest to do some other tutorials on Flash to understand how to work with actionscript. Gotoandlearn.com has nice ones. Enjoy!